# How do I make a combo box in a grid view drop down in a single click?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Combo-box in a Grid view, which takes 3 clicks in order to open the drop down menu. I want to make this activate in a single click.

As far as I can tell the first click selects the cell, the second selects the control (the combo box) and the third click makes the combo box open the drop down menu. Subsequent clicks on the same cell will open and close the drop down menu as the user expects.

From comment:

```
List<string> values = new List<string>();
values.Add("Text");
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
col.DataSource = values;
dataGridView.Columns.Add(col);
dataGridView.Rows.Add();
```

Comment: A code example could help here.

Comment: just seen this, code would be helpful, what have you tried?
as far as i can tell quickly try setting focus on an event maybe.

Comment: List<string> values = new List<string>();
values.Add("Text");

DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
col.DataSource = values;
dataGridView.Columns.Add(col);

dataGridView.Rows.Add();

Comment: Sorry don't know how to format in this yet.
I trying to make the on-click event select the control within the grid view, but I don't know how to access an instance of a combo box control within a column / row

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the DataGridView control, try setting this property:

```
dataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter;
```

Comment: This takes it down to 2 clicks to open the drop down box. Although is there a way to apply this to only a single column? Otherwise the rest of the grid view does not work correctly.

Comment: @Carlos It is only one click on my form.  Does the form with the DataGridView already have the focus?  Otherwise, you might have something else interfering, especially since you say `the rest of the grid does not work correctly`.  What does that mean?  Check the events you are already using, because that's probably where the problem is.

Comment: The form has focus. By not work correctly I mean that all the other cells are now in edit mode in a single click (and now I can't access the context menu for them). I think 2 clicks is my ideal. For a normal text cell clicking on it selects it, the second click puts you in edit mode. So I would want drop down boxes to open on 2 clicks and cells to be editable on 2 clicks. EditOnEnter makes this 2, 1 instead of 3, 2.<br> If I can't apply this to an individual column I'll have to look at using the on-click event for the combo box cells.